# Problem handling onchange on a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a GridView with textboxes in its cells. I need to call a javascript function when the user changes the contents of a TextBox, and then hits Enter or leaves the TextBox. The latter is achieved by doing onchange="MyJavascriptFunc", but the javascript function is not called when Enter is pressed. If I call the javascript function from EnterKeyPressHandler function, MyJavascriptFunc is called twice, which I would prefer to avoid.
Could you please help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the func is called when the user presses enter.

```
  var called = false;
  if(called != true) 
  {
       called = true;
       // and do sth
  }
  called = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I am missing something, but it seems to me that called will be always false, as you assign it right before the if() check.

Comment: Sorry.I did not notice that.Declare the called outside of the scope of the method.

Comment: mootinator, I wish I could mark your last message, too, but don't know where.

Comment: @dpreznik No worries, I'm fairly incoherent today =)